# Editing TextField move Animated UIView to its original position Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

On Swipe up I animated a view from bottom of the screen, using below code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations)
```

along with

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

But as my view contains TextField, when I start typing and press any key the view returns back to its original position at start. So in short I guess the animated view's update constraints are not retained.

Can anyone please help me fix this I tried many options.

```
@objc func handleSwipe(_ sender : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        if sender.direction == .up{
            switch self.currentIndex {
            case 0:
                self.assetsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.assetsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollUpY , width: self.assetsView.frame.size.width, height: self.assetsView.frame.size.height)
                self.liabilitiesView.frame = CGRect(x: self.liabilitiesView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollDownY , width: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.width, height: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.height)
                break
            case 1:
                self.assetsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.assetsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.originalTopY , width: self.assetsView.frame.size.width, height: self.assetsView.frame.size.height)
                self.liabilitiesView.frame = CGRect(x: self.liabilitiesView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollUpY , width: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.width, height: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.height)
                self.savingsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.savingsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollDownY , width: self.savingsView.frame.size.width, height: self.savingsView.frame.size.height)
                break
            case 2:
                self.liabilitiesView.frame = CGRect(x: self.liabilitiesView.frame.origin.x, y: self.originalTopY , width: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.width, height: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.height)
                self.savingsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.savingsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollUpY , width: self.savingsView.frame.size.width, height: self.savingsView.frame.size.height)
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                QL1("Success")
            }
        }else if sender.direction == .down{
            switch self.currentIndex {
            case 0:
                self.assetsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.assetsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollDownY , width: self.assetsView.frame.size.width, height: self.assetsView.frame.size.height)
                self.liabilitiesView.frame = CGRect(x: self.liabilitiesView.frame.origin.x, y: self.originalDownY , width: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.width, height: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.height)
                break
            case 1:
                self.assetsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.assetsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollUpY , width: self.assetsView.frame.size.width, height: self.assetsView.frame.size.height)
                self.liabilitiesView.frame = CGRect(x: self.liabilitiesView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollDownY , width: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.width, height: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.height)
                self.savingsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.savingsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.originalDownY , width: self.savingsView.frame.size.width, height: self.savingsView.frame.size.height)
                break
            case 2:
                self.assetsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.assetsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.originalTopY , width: self.assetsView.frame.size.width, height: self.assetsView.frame.size.height)
                self.liabilitiesView.frame = CGRect(x: self.liabilitiesView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollUpY , width: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.width, height: self.liabilitiesView.frame.size.height)
                self.savingsView.frame = CGRect(x: self.savingsView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollDownY , width: self.savingsView.frame.size.width, height: self.savingsView.frame.size.height)
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                QL1("Success")
            }
        }
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        self.updateScreen(sender)
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Layout Constraints]

Comment: Can you show all of the code please?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I have added my code of animation.

Comment: Are you using Auto layout? please show how is your `TextField` constraints inside the view

Comment: Added Constraints, no I haven't used auto layout

Comment: What do you have in your textfield delegates?

Answer (score 0):

You can try CGAffineTransform. For translation;

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xOffset, y: yOffset)
}
```

And for return back to its original position;

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
```